# Why doesn't error occur in UDP socket communication?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp, udpclient

I am a student studying computer networking.
I made very simple server-client socket communication program in C on Ubuntu, using UDP protocol.
I read in the book that UDP is unreliable data transferring protocol while TCP is reliable data transferring protocol. The reason is that UDP is just sending packets while TCP is sending and waiting for receiving corresponding ack message.

Anyhow, I tried many times to send an image file (around 1Mb) from client to server using UDP socket. However, the image file was transmitted successfully without any one failure.

Does socket library have error correction scheme although UDP setting?

ps) My program is almost the same as the common echo socket code in C. Just different thing is not echoing but copying. That is, client transfers data and server receives and copies it.

For reference) I used sys/socket header for socket functions. I used fopen, fread and fwrite for copying file.

Comment: So your network and the IP stack of your computers doesn't drop or corrupt any packets - and you receive all the packets just fine. Being unreliable doesn't mean errors happen without reason. You could try to send a (much) larger file, in which case the chance for filling up buffers at the receiver increases (and packets get dropped).

Comment: @nos How can I see packet dropping phenomenon? I am doing this program with two terminals. One is client and the other is server. So, I am using local IP address 127.0.0.1 and port number 9999.

Comment: Communications on loopback interface happen through local memory with no network involved. Try on two separate machines.

Comment: @Danny_Kim As I mentioned, try with a bigger file. UDP does not have flow control, so if you send faster than you receive, packets will be dropped. Or you could try sending through an ethernet switch whilst also transferring files using other means, so you max out the capacity of the ports on the ethernet switch, in which case it will drop packets.

Comment: Thank you. I will try with bigger file and separate machine!

Comment: Packet loss *does* sometimes occur on real networks, and packets sometimes do arrive at their destination in a different order then the one in which they were sent.  UDP is "unreliable" because it provides no built-in means to detect or recover from these events.  Whether you are likely actually to encounter such errors is an entirely different question, depending mostly on the network and network conditions.

Comment: "*send an image file (around 1Mb) from client to server using UDP*" - that is too much data for a single UDP packet to physically hold, so you have to break up the data into multiple packets. And that introduces the possibility of lost data due to dropped packets, data getting out of order, etc. UDP is not good for data transfers when reliability is needed. However, there are protocols that add an element of reliability to UDP, like [Trivial FTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol), [Reliable UDP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol), etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyhow, I tried many times to send an image file (around 1Mb) from client to server using UDP socket. However, the image file was transmitted successfully without any one failure.

If done on a single host via loopback no packet will be lost (except if you enable some packet loss testing function). That is because modern OSs' network layer only passes around pointers to packet descriptors. So when you do a `send()` or `write()` on a socket a packet descriptor struct is constructed around your data; that struct kind of "lives" in the writing process and only a pointer to it is passed to whoever is going to receive it. If it's another process this results effectively in IPC (and if you use the right socket operations this goes even as far as a zero-copy data transfer). Only if that packet descriptor ends up within a network interface driver, more than just that pointer will be passed around.

On a local network it's also next to impossible to loose a packet, because collision detection happens on the link layer and modern switches are store and forward architectures. It takes a *huge* amount of network load for noticing any form of packet loss back pressure.

For packet loss to become noticeable you must either use a highly contended shared medium network (say, W-LAN with a lot of clients contending for it) or go through at least one router close to its bandwidth capacity.

> Does socket library have error correction scheme although UDP setting?

No.

Comment: Note that UDP doesn't have flow control, even on loopback devices. So if you send faster than you receive, you see packet drops there too, after the socket buffers overflow

Comment: @nos Very detail explanation!!! I am impressed! Thank you very much. After completely making this socket communication program, I will make transport layer program too. Is there any library connecting transport layer and ip layer, like socket which connects app layer and transport layer?

Comment: @Danny_Kim: I think you're trying to reinvent userspace IP stacks here. If this is a pure learning experience, then go for it. But if this is for a practical application then you probably should not approach this without some significant networking experience under your belt. Anyway if you want a reliable datagram connection then you should look at SCTP instead of UDP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error correction in UDP. It is still unreliable, even though you succeeded many time to transfer a file using it.

The probability of error is very small in today's networks, especially in a LAN or on the same machine. That is, you may need to try sending a file millions of times before you get an error.